# Rails: link_to with :remote => true not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a voting system kind of like the one here on Stack Overflow. (Using Rails 3) I want the voting to be done without a page reload, so I have this code

```
link_to("/tags/#{tag.id}/upVote", :remote => true )
```

And so in my /views/tags directory I have a file called _upVote.js.erb that I thought would be called when this link is clicked, but it is not. It is trying to process upVote as HTML and this is the error I get

> Missing template tags/upVote with {:formats=>[:html]

Also, here is what I have in my routes file

```
match "tags/:id/upVote" => "tags#upVote"
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: I deleted the answer, since that wasn't the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you got this error message in a blank new page, that means that your remote call does not work and the call wasn't made via an Ajax request. You need to check that your layout correctly loads jQuery and the jQuery Rails connector available here : http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Then use Firefox+Firebug to check that the call is really an Ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. 
To resolve the problem, I followed

- https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails
- [Rails 4 rendering a partial with ajax, jquery, :remote => true, and respond_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808696/rails-4-rendering-a-partial-with-ajax-jquery-remote-true-and-respond-to)

And finally, I had to

```
Require both jquery and jquery_ujs were in the application.js manifest.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

After all that, Rails ajax started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

See this post for a solution:

[Rails form_for :remote=>true is not calling js method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method)

When changing the rails environment to JQuery, you may accidentally lose your jquery-ujs file.

Answer (score 0):

type something like inside your rails application root:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

And then, inside your `application.html.erb` add the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

or explicitly (do not forget to include your jquery separately):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :rails, :application %>
```

[EDIT: for Rails 3.1 or greater using the asset pipeline]

Use the `gem jquery-rails` (as mentioned above) and add the following lines to the **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** (if they are not there already) :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Hope this helps!