# Rails form_for :remote=>true is not calling js method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have no idea why this is not working, I'm learning rails and I'm following a book it says to do it like this:

```
    <%= form_for([@article,@article.comments.new ], :remote=>true, :html => {:style=>'display: none;' }) do |f|%>
    <div class="field">
      <%=    f.label :name %>
      <%=    f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%=    f.label :email %>
      <%=    f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%=    f.label :body %>
      <%=    f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

However it does not work, and when I check the request in firebug the url doesnt end in .js, do you have any ideas why?

Comment: can you add according controller-methods (e. g. index, create, new) and the related view files here, so we can see the whole picture ?

Answer (score 36):

When you check the request made in firebug, just because the url did not end with .js, it does not mean that it was not called from javascript. To verify that you should check the request header to see what the Accept parameter is. If it says "application/javascript" then it's all good.

Secondly, a very common problem when starting to try out the :remote => true is that the required javascript libraries are not included in your code. So my guess is that the following code is missing from your layout:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

If that is the case, just include it inside the `<head>` tag of your layout.

Comment: do you mean by "html header" the head tag of the template where the form/link with the remote:true is?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. That was not so clear. But yes, it should be included inside to <head> tag

Answer (score 22):

Most likely what happens is that you are missing the `rails.js` file, which handles that for you, whether you are using prototype or jquery.

If you are using jQuery, the easiest way to get all the needed files is using the `jquery-rails` gem. This will add a generator to install jquery and the needed rails.js.

type something like inside your rails application root:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

And then, inside your `application.html.erb` add the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

or explicitly (do not forget to include your jquery separately):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :rails, :application %>
```

[EDIT: for Rails 3.1 or greater using the asset pipeline]

Use the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem (as mentioned above) and add the following lines to the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` (if they are not there already) :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: We had this issue but we included `jquery_ujs.js` to fix it.

Comment: Yes, true, it changed a bit with rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

Check your `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` file

It should be included below files in there. `jquery_ujs` is responsible for working `remote=> true` feature.

```
require `jquery`
require `jquery_ujs`
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: I had a similar newbie issue while following `Agile Web Development with Rails`, on `chapter 11.2 Iteration F2: Creating an AJAX-Based Cart`. The problem is solved by uncomment `= require jquery` in the file your listed. Hope this helps for other people.

Comment: That's Great @cppinitiator!

Answer (score 7):

This error occurs when you have not add **jquery_ujs** file. You just included the jquery file.

So you need to add both files manually in you view or require them in **application.js** or any other file which you are using for specific **layout**.

Depending upon your scenario, you can follow 1st or 2nd solution.

**1st solution:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :jquery, :jquery_ujs %>
```

**2nd solution:**

1. Require both **jquery** and **jquery_ujs** in **app/assets/application.js**

   ```
   //= require jquery.js

   //= require jquery_ujs
   ```
2. Include application.js file in your specific **layout** file.

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
   ```

**Note:**

Also add csrf tag in layout file for both solutions.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

I'm asuming that you have below code in your Gemfile and already installed this Gem.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the controller: does it have a respond_to block?

If you generated your app with rails generate scaffold, it will have something like

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml  { .... }
    end
```

If it does have it, just take the whole block out, from respond_to to end; or alternatively replace the whole block with the single line

```
    respond_to :html, :js
```

or alternatively edit the block by adding the extra line shown here

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.xml  { .... }
    end
```

Either should work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file_field then it submits as html, even when `remote: true` - took me a long time to work that out so I am adding this answer to maybe save someone else time, there is a solution, use the remotipart gem, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132509/remote-true-option-is-not-working-with-file-field-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above answers solve it for you, double check if you are not rendering your `remote: true` (or `local: false`) form **nested within another form in the page**. This was causing the issue for us.

Answer (score -11):

Change:

```
[@article,@article.comments.new ]
```

for

```
@article
```

I suggest you reading the API on the related section : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: ryudice is looking to have a new comments form for the article ryudice is on.  ryudice's form_for call is the correct syntax for what ryudice is wanting.  Your suggestion would be fine for a standard article form. It's confusing, because the context is never stated.