# form_for [@parent,@son],:remote=>true not asking for JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a plain old form. That form is used to create new objects of a nested model.

```
#restaurant.rb
has_many :courses
#courses.rb
belongs_to :restaurant
#routes.rb
resources :restaurants do
  resources :courses
end
```

In my views(in haml), i have that code:

```
%li.course{'data-random'=>random}
  = form_for([restaurant,course], :remote=>true) do |f|
    .name= f.text_field :name, :placeholder=>'Name here'
    .cat= f.hidden_field :category
    .price= f.text_field :price,:placeholder=>'Price here'
    .save
      = hidden_field_tag :random,random
      = f.submit "Save"
```

I espected that form to be answered by action create of courses_controller with JS (create.js.erb), but it is submited like a normal form, and is answered with html.

What am I doing wrong? This problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remotetrue-is-not-calling-js-method) but the only answer don't make sense to me.
 Thanks

Inside

Comment: Could you post the related controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have in your controller respond with js format `format.js { render :layout => false }` and your create view should be `create.js.rjs`(i am talking about rails 3)