# Why is a controller respond_to that is set to js returning only html in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why is my controller action only returning in HTML format even when I explicitly state that it can only return as of type JS?

app/controllers/classrooms_controller.rb

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # This doesn't work.
  end
end
```

app/views/classrooms/new.html.haml

```
= form_tag classrooms_path, :html => {:multipart => true}, do |f|
  = text_field_tag :name
  = submit_tag "Done"
```

app/views/classrooms/create.js.erb

```
alert('hi');
```

Server

```
Started POST "/classrooms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-04 18:17:22 -0800
Processing by ClassroomsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z+rsjO1rY2+P7VdsYd/LwiQr3DZX6r1/Dxh7JGbIOFA=", "name"=>"feed", "commit"=>"Done"}
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 2ms
```

I get a blank page with no code (checked the source) in the browser.

Comment: can you include the full log of the request ?

Comment: Ok, updated. thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it says "406 Not Acceptable", you are making HTML request from the form but your controller only respond to JS request.

Try adding :remote => true to the form

```
= form_tag classrooms_path, :html => {:multipart => true}, :remote => true, do |f|
```

If that doesn't work, you probably haven't include these:

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults
= csrf_meta_tag
```

in your html header (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method)

Comment: What does 406 Not Acceptable represent?  Its very vague and not helpful for diagnosing problems..

Comment: thats html error code, This will help you, http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html. Basically by using format.js only, you are saying you only accept JS request, however the request created from the form is HTML by default (unless you use the :remote => true).