# Ruby On Rails: Ajax to Refresh Partial Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am having a difficult time trying to get my partial to refresh on button press. I want to simply refresh the div, and not the whole page. Here is what I have in the view:

```
<div id="ajax">
  <%= render 'layouts/confessions' %>
</div>
```

Then in my partial `_confessions.html.erb`, I have some basic html and two buttons similar to this:

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => :confessions, :action => :upvote, :id => conf.id }, { :method => :put } ) do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Like' %>
<% end %>
```

My confessions_controller.rb:

```
def upvote
  @confession = Confession.find(params[:id])    
  Confession.increment_counter :upvotes, @confession
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And finally, `upvote.js.erb`:

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'confessions')).html_safe %>");
```

The action of submitting to my database is working, but the page is now redirecting to  `/upvote?id=9` (id can be different), instead of just refreshing the div. What am I doing wrong? I am new to Rails, so I could be missing something completely obvious...

EDIT: Here is my folder structure:

My view: `views/pages/home.html.erb`

My partial: `views/layouts/_confessions.html.erb`

My Controller: `controllers/confessions_controller.rb`

My js.erb file: `views/confessions/upvote.js.erb`

After `rake routes`

```
    confessions GET    /confessions(.:format)            confessions#index
                POST   /confessions(.:format)            confessions#create
new_confession  GET    /confessions/new(.:format)        confessions#new
edit_confession GET    /confessions/:id/edit(.:format)   confessions#edit
 confession     GET    /confessions/:id(.:format)        confessions#show
                PUT    /confessions/:id(.:format)        confessions#update
                DELETE /confessions/:id(.:format)        confessions#destroy
     upvote            /upvote(.:format)                 confessions#upvote
   downvote            /downvote(.:format)               confessions#downvote
       root            /                                 pages#home
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have this in your application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

FYI: [Rails form_for :remote=>true is not calling js method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method)

Then, change this,

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'confessions')).html_safe %>");
```

To:

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'layouts/confessions')).html_safe %>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add :remote => true

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => :confessions, :action => :upvote, :id => conf.id }, { :method => :put, :remote=>true } ) do %>
```

Also - read up on rails routes to see how to setup the route for PUT confessions/upvote.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Sorry, had that in the wrong order. See the edit. { :method => :put, :remote=>true }

Comment: Still just redirects me...Did you see my edit? Do I have the upvote.js.erb in the right area?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Should be in the same location as your views for confessions.

Comment: Hmm..no idea what is wrong then. Do I have to add something in my routes??

Comment: Run `rake routes`. Make sure there is something like... PUT /confessions(.:format) {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"confessions"}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24996/discussion-between-mc6688-and-adback03)

Comment: Shouldn't you use `form_remote_tag` or something instead of `form_tag`?