# Processing by xController#show / update as HTML instead as JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table in my database and I'm showing in a page.

The problem happens when I am saving the changes.

I need the Rails process using js and not redirect the user to another page when you click save.

So far, I can save changes but I am always redirected to other pages processed by HTML instead JS.

**controller**:

```
filter_resource_access :nested_in => :releases
filter_resource_access :nested_in => :project

respond_to :js, only: [:update, :edit, :show]
respond_to :html

before_filter :load_issue, :load_project, :load_release

def edit
end

def update
  if @issue_value.update_attributes(params[:issue_value])
    flash.now[:notice] = t('messages.successfully_updated_entity.f',
                                             :entity => IssueValue.model_name.human)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**_issue_values_table**:

```
<table class="zebra-striped">

 <thead>
 <tr>
   <th><%= IssueValue.human_attribute_name :name %></th>
   <th><%= IssueValue.human_attribute_name :value %></th>
   <th><%= IssueValue.human_attribute_name :client_value %></th>
   <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @issue_types = IssueType %>
<% for issue_value in @release.issue_values.order("issue_type_id") %>
  <%= content_tag_for :tr, issue_value, :class => "clickable" do %>
    <td width="42%"><%#= t(@issue_types.find(issue_value.issue_type_id).label_key) %></td>
    <td width="20%">
      <%= number_to_currency issue_value.value %>
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
      <%= number_to_currency issue_value.client_value %>
    </td>
    <td width="12%" class="icons right">
      <%= edit_icon issue_value, [:edit, @project, @release, issue_value], :remote => true, 'data-default-action' => true %>
    </td>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

**_form_row**:

```
 <td colspan="4">
   <%= form_for [@project, @release, @issue_value], :remote => true, :html => {:style => "margin:0"} do |f| %>
  <table class="basic">
    <tr>
      <td class="span8 middle">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <%#= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => IssueType.human_attribute_name(:name),
                           :autofocus => true, :class => "span10" %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="span5 middle">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <%= f.text_field :value, :placeholder => IssueValue.human_attribute_name(:value),
                   :autofocus => true, :class => "span2" %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="span5 middle">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <%= f.text_field :client_value, :placeholder => IssueValue.human_attribute_name(:client_value),
                   :class => "span2" %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="span2 icons">
        <%= f.submit t('actions.save'), :disable_with => t('messages.please_wait'), :class => 'btn small', :remote => true %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

In views/issue_values I have:

1. edit.js.erb
2. show.js.erb
3. update.js.erb
4. _form_row.html.erb
5. _issue_values_table.html.erb

Well, I don't undestand why this not works.

The Log is:

> Started GET "/projects/pro-/releases/release02/values/14/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-13 08:39:36 -0200
>     Processing by IssueValuesController#edit as JS
>     Parameters: {"project_id"=>"pro-", "release_id"=>"release02", "id"=>"14"}
>     SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
>     User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE ((`users`.`auth_token` = 'ji2lt8p1185q6q1l' AND `users`.`status_id` = 2)) LIMIT 1
>     SQL (1.5ms)  describe `releases_browser_versions`
>     SQL (0.6ms)  describe `releases_os_versions`
>     SQL (0.7ms)  describe `releases_mobile_models`
>     Release Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `releases`.* FROM `releases` WHERE `releases`.`identifier` = 'release02' LIMIT 1
>     IssueValue Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `issue_values`.* FROM `issue_values` WHERE `issue_values`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
>     SQL (0.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
>     Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`identifier` = 'pro-' LIMIT 1
>     CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `issue_values`.* FROM `issue_values` WHERE `issue_values`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
>   Rendered issue_values/_form_row.html.erb (34.6ms)
>   Rendered issue_values/edit.js.erb (36.1ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 642ms (Views: 50.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
>   [2013-12-13 08:39:36] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
>
> Started POST "/projects/pro-/releases/release02/values/14" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-13 08:39:37 -0200
>     Processing by IssueValuesController#update as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vuyP9Jwm4pS63OF7xucBHGo0L5m61ayj3aWcXYpFTKM=", "issue_value"=>{"value"=>"10,00", "client_value"=>"5,00"}, "commit"=>"Salvar", "project_id"=>"pro-", "release_id"=>"release02", "id"=>"14"}
>     SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
>     User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE ((`users`.`auth_token` = 'ji2lt8p1185q6q1l' AND `users`.`status_id` = 2)) LIMIT 1
>     SQL (0.7ms)  describe `releases_browser_versions`
>     SQL (0.5ms)  describe `releases_os_versions`
>     SQL (0.6ms)  describe `releases_mobile_models`
>     Release Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `releases`.* FROM `releases` WHERE `releases`.`identifier` = 'release02' LIMIT 1
>     IssueValue Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `issue_values`.* FROM `issue_values` WHERE `issue_values`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
>     SQL (0.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
>     Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`identifier` = 'pro-' LIMIT 1
>     CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `issue_values`.* FROM `issue_values` WHERE `issue_values`.`id` = 14 LIMIT 1
>     SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>     SQL (0.1ms)  COMMIT
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 784ms
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template issue_values/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:pt, :pt]} in view paths "/var/www/base2_crowdtest/2112/final/trunk/app/views", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.4/app/views", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/declarative_authorization-0.5.6/app/views", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views"):
>     app/controllers/issue_values_controller.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in update'
>     app/controllers/issue_values_controller.rb:11:in`block in update'
>     app/controllers/issue_values_controller.rb:9:in `update'
>
> Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)

Someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a redirect then just remove it. And [add respond_to/respond_with to controller](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with). Also you'll need update.js.erb for handling situation when record is successfully saved. Like that:

```
class IssueValuesController < LoginRequiredController
  respond_to :js, only: [:update]
  respond_to :html
  filter_resource_access :nested_in => :releases 

  def update
    if @issue_value.update_attributes(params[:issue_value])
      flash.now[:notice] = t('messages.successfully_updated_entity.f',
                                                 :entity => IssueValue.model_name.human)
    end
    respond_with(@issue_value)
  end

# rest of the class ommited
end
```

**Workaround**:

try changing your form to:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @release, @issue_value], :remote => true, :html => {:format => "js", :style => "margin:0"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: I tried this: `def update
     if @issue_value.update_attributes(params[:issue_value])
        flash[:notice] = "Customer was successfully updated."
        @issue_value = IssueValue.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js`
        end
      end
  end`, and I created the file update.js.rb, but still dont works.

Comment: Do you have "jquery-rails" installed? Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6186264/1432212).

Comment: In log show: Processing by IssueValuesController#edit as JS Parameters. I checked too and I have that gem.

Comment: Please see the workaround. Although it's weird that your current approach isn't working. I'm pretty sure that you don't need `@issue_value = IssueValue.all` part.

Comment: I don't created the controller using generate, could be that?

Comment: No, that's clearly not an issue. Did workaround worked?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43129/discussion-between-vadim-chumel-and-lorena)

Comment: @VadimChumel Wow, that suggestion to add `:remote => true,` to the form tag has got it working after 5 hours of trying!! Thank you.