# Rails rendering JavaScript as text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a remote form in my Rails 4 application for my `Artists` model. I have another form for my `Shows`, and the `Shows` form has a link that can be clicked if the user wishes to add a new `Artist` to the database from inside the `Shows` form. Clicking that link sends a `GET` request to `/artists/new` and the `ArtistsController` assigns `@artist` a new `Artist` and then renders `new.js.erb`, which hides the link to add a new `Artist` and renders the form for a new `Artist` in its place.

The form is rendered fine, and when I click submit a `POST` request is sent and it is routed to the `create` method in my `ArtistsController` The server then sends a response back that is in my `create.js.erb` file, but that response is interpreted by the browser as html. Instead of executing the JavaScript that is in `create.js.erb` it just displays the code in the browser.

Here is my `Shows` form

```
= form_for @show, html: {role: 'form'} do |f|
  - if @show.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this venue from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @show.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .row
    = f.label :venue_id
    = f.collection_select :venue_id, Venue.all, :id, :name, class: 'form-control'
  .row
    .col-sm-6
      = link_to 'New Artist', new_artist_path, id: :new_artist_link, remote: true
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :date
        = f.date_select :show_date, order: [:day, :month, :year], class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :doors_open
        = f.time_select :doors_open, class: 'form-control'
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :dinner_starts
        = f.time_select :dinner_starts, class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :show_starts
        = f.time_select :show_starts, class: 'form-control'
  .row.row-centered
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :dinner_ends
        = f.time_select :dinner_ends, class: 'form-control'
    .col-sm-6
      .form-group
        = f.label :show_ends
        = f.time_select :show_ends, class: 'form-control'

  .form-group
    = f.submit 'Save Show', class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Here is my `Artists` form

```
= form_for(@artist, remote: true, authenticity_token: true, format: :js) do |f|
  - if @artist.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@artist.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this artist from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @artist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Submit'
```

Here is my `ArtistsController new` and `create` methods

```
  def new
    @artist = Artist.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @artist = Artist.new(artist_params)

    if @artist.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        end
      end
    end
```

Here is my `new.js.erb`

```
$('#new_artist_link').hide().after("<%= j render 'form' %>");
```

My `create.js.erb`. I had actual code in here, but removed it, and just replaced it with this until I can figure out the problem.

```
$('h1').hide();
```

I spent all day yesterday trying to figure this out and am totally baffled.

EDIT: Writing the following jQuery in my `new.js.erb` and adding `post 'artists/create` to my routes allowed me to post the data, the problem was that the accept header of the post was not accepting JavaScript. Is there a way to not have to write the entire ajax request and to just modify the existing one to accept javascript?

Updated `create.js.erb`

```
$('#new_artist_link').hide().after("<%= j render 'form' %>");
$('#new_artist_link').remove();
$('#new_artist').submit(function() {

    var url = "/artists/create"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#new_artist").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        accepts: 'application/javascript'
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: Is this an ajax request? If so where is ajax code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method seem to point to the same issue. I would also check the generated HTML tag for the form to see if data-remote="true" is there.

Comment: @charlietfl As far as I understand it, Rails should use ujs to generate the ajax code because I put remote: true, right?

Comment: I don't know much about rails, but even if it is generated by rails the browser still has to be sent the code to run. Seeing that would help

Comment: @Mingsheng Okay, that helped. Thanks! It turned out I had to modify the accepts header to take javascript. I included an edit in my post showing what I had to do - is there a simpler way to do this that is rails-native and doesn't involve the jQuery?

Comment: You probably should add the answer to this question instead since u got it figured out. Likely might help someone else in the future who didn't manage to find the other post. Not sure about the other issue though. Glad it helped.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'm totally baffled why Rails isn't working like it used to.  I've been programming Rails and remote forms for over 8 years and these have always "just worked".  This seems like an issue that should be submitted to the Rails Core team or the `jquery-rails` team.  Adding "remote: true" should be all you need to do here - the framework should set the Accept headers properly, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem - my `POST` accept header did not include `text/javascript`, so I had to add the following to my `new.js.erb`

```
$('#new_artist').submit(function() {

    var url = "/artists/create"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#new_artist").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        accepts: 'application/javascript'
    });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

I also had to add `post 'artists/create'` to my `routes.rb`