# Implementing AJAX Creation, Missing Template (Create) Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to implement AJAX in my to do type app, but am getting a missing template error (`Missing template items/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.`) on my create action.  There shouldn't be a `create.html.erb` page because the creation of `items` happens on a `lists#show` page:

```
<div class='new-item'>
  <%= render 'items/form' %>
</div>

<div class="js-items">
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= div_for(item) do %>
      <p><%= link_to "", list_item_path(@list, item), method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', style: "margin-right: 10px" %>
       <%= item.name %>
      <% if item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id == current_user.id %>
        <small>(Delegated to <%= item.delegated_to %>)</small>
      <% elsif item.delegated_to != "" && item.user_id != current_user.id %>
        <small>(Delegated by <%= item.user_id %>)</small>
      <% end %></p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And the `_form.html.erb` partial to which it links:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <%= form_for [@list, @item], remote: true do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Item Name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <%= f.label 'Delegate To (Not Required)' %>
        <%= f.text_field :delegated_to, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter an Email Address" %>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Add Item to List", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the `create` method in the `items_controller`:

```
  def create
    @list = List.friendly.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = @list.items.new(item_params)
    @item.user = current_user
    @new_item = Item.new

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Item failed to save."
    end

    respond_to do |format|   <<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And here's my `create.js.erb` file:

```
<% if @item.valid? %>
  $('.js-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");
  $('.new-item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/form', locals: { list: @list, item: @new_item }) %>");
<% else %>
  $('.flash').prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><%= flash.now[:alert] %></div>");
  $('.new-item').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items/form', locals: { list: @list, item: @item }) %>");
<% end %>
```

Anyone have any ideas why I am getting this? I tried removing the `format.html` line from the `items_controller` but I got an unrecognizable format error.

Comment: Remove the  format.html, you definitely don't need it. However, try to comment out your create.js.erb file but leave a simple console.log to see if the error is coming from what's in the file

Comment: Without 'format.html` I get `ActionController::UnknownFormat` on the `respond_to do |format|` line. (Even with `console.log` instead of the js file content.)

Comment: Your form is not successfully requesting with a JS format.  That is, the `remote: true` option is not being handled properly.  Check this question for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227775/rails-form-for-remote-true-is-not-calling-js-method

Comment: @sealocal, this post is a great resource, but I have a `javascript_include_tag` and a `csrf_meta_tags` in my application header and I have AJAX deletion working just fine with a JS format.

Comment: If you remove `remote: true` from your AJAX deletion `link_to` helper, does your AJAX deletion still work? Or are you processing you sending your creation and deletion requests with your own code, such as a click handler on the submit button?

Comment: When you inspect the `form` element in the DOM, do you see the `data-remote="true"` attribute?

Comment: @sealocal, without `remote: true` the deletion does not work. And it looks like the items are in fact being created before the error appears.

Comment: And yes, the `data-remote="true"` is in the form.

Comment: You could try `<%= form_for([@list, @item], format: :js, remote: true) do |f| %>` to ensure that the request specifies a `js` response/format.

Comment: No luck.  I'm getting this in my server log: `  Rendered items/create.js.erb (8.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial items/_item with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/.../bloc/code/blocitoff/app/views"
  * "/Users/.../.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-4.1.1/app/views"`

Comment: Also, look at your http request to see the type. Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client.  Make sure that the request is being generated as a javascript request type.

Comment: @hightempo, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Oh, looks like your error has changed.  It's now rendering your create.js.erb but is looking for a partial called _item.  That is probably because of the line " $('.js-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");"

Comment: It seems like you have the format issue solved and are now just missing a partial that you really should have, but for future reference you should be able to examine the request through the 'request' object in your controller.  If you're using a tool for debugging like pry, put a binding in your controller action and look at request.format.  If not, you can inspect it with puts and that will write it to the logs, but it's a huge messy object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the form submission to use a JS format, instead of the default HTML format, so that your `respond_to` block will render the `create.js.erb` view instead of the `create.html.erb` view.

```
<%= form_for([@list, @item], format: :js, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Typically, Rails will detect your `remote: true` option via "unobtrusive JavaScript (ujs)", which will effectively handle the `format: :js` option for you. There is something unique in your setup that we have not identified, which is requiring you to enforce the `format` option.

To see that your `create.js.erb` is working, you can change the line that renders your `item` partial:

```
$('.js-items').prepend("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");
```

To render a the item's name, wrapped in a `<p>` tag:

```
$('.js-items').prepend("<p>" + <%= @item.name %> + "</p>");
```

You can customize that line to generate the html that you want to appear for your new list item.  Based on your code above, this looks like it will work out for you.

As you finish your to-do app, you can create a partial for your item, and then change that line again so that your partial will be appended to your list of items.

Comment: All of this worked, except it still requires a manual refresh to get the form to clear and the new item to appear on the list...

Comment: You should double-check that `$('.js-items)` returns the correct DOM element to which you want to prepend (`<div class="js-items">`).  You can run `$('.js-items)` in your browser console.  Then you can attempt to prepend arbitrary HTML. It seems there is something in your jQuery code that is not manipulating the DOM the way that you wish.