# Calling ajax:beforeSend and ajax:complete on any link_to where remote is true ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm working on a webapp using Ruby on Rails as framework. For all the partial renders, we used link_to with remote true as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808696/rails-4-rendering-a-partial-with-ajax-jquery-remote-true-and-respond-to) answer. However, I would like to bind the all those links to something equivalent to ajax:beforeSend and ajax:complete in order to implement a loader anytime a page is called in jQuery. So far I tried the following but it is not working :

```
$('a').on('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  alert("BEFORE");
});

$('a').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  alert("AFTER");
});
```

So if you have any other ideas it would be really appreciated if you could let me know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's an example of how I have been using link_to :

```
<%= link_to({action: "show_card", controller: "pages", id: activ.id, method: :get, :remote => true}, class: "nav-link p-0") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is not working `ajax` or `loader` if your ajax is working then for loader it should be like this

```
<div id="mySpinner" style="displany:none;">
     <img src="loader.gif">
</div>

$(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        //$("#mySpinner").show();
         alert("BEFORE");
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        //$("#mySpinner").hide();
        alert("AFTER");
    });
});
```

Comment: Right now I'm just testing for the ajax function with an alert so it is the ajax event that is not being called I think. @fool-dev

Comment: If your `ajax` run after clicking the link then `#mySpinner` div automatically show

Comment: I don't think againStart is being triggered by link_to though I guess that is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

How about to show loader on element `onclick` event and hide it on `ajax:success`?

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
  alert("BEFORE");
});

$('a').ob('ajax:success', function() {
  alert("AFTER");
});
```

Make sure to also cover `ajax:error`

You might also try to subscribe to `ajax:send` instead of `ajax:beforeSend`. Because `ajax:beforeSend` is a local event and can be subscribed to only within the Ajax request object [as docs say](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was, when I render new staff partially, I need to rebind it to the event, and apparently even using

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('a').on('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  alert("BEFORE");
});

$('a').bind('ajax:complete', function() {
  alert("AFTER");
});
});
```

In the application.js file did not work, so basically to bind it initially I had to put a script tag at the bottom of my page which binds everything once it already rendered everything. Furthermore, anytime I do any remote partial rendering, I also need to rebind everything in the .js.erb file, that way it actually works. I'm there has to be a better way because this seems an awful solution; it is however, a solution for now.